# Django inline formset Select Field overide with search and select field by JS/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I have models as Client, ClientSubUser

```
Client(models.Modal):
  name = ...
  address = ...
  user = models.ForeignKey(User)

ClientSubUser(models.Model):
  client = models.ForeignKey(Client)
  user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

Admin:

```
class ClientSubUserInline( admin.StackedInline ):
    model = ClientSubUser
    extra = 0

class ClientAdmin( admin.ModelAdmin ):
    form = ClientAdminForm
    search_fields = ('name',)
    list_display = ('name','adress')
    inlines = (ClientSubUserInline,)

    class Media:
        css = { 
                'all': ("select2/select2.css",),
                }       jQuery("#id_user").select2({'placeholder': "Select a Locality"});
        js = ("select2/select2.js, client_admin_utils.js")
```

now if i have to make client user as search and select,
then i simply select field on ready by java script in client_admin_utils,

jQuery("#id_user").select2({'placeholder': "Select a Locality"});

and it becomes search n select,
but problem occurse in inline, cause inline populate only when we click on "add another" link, i.e. by django admin jquery itself,

I want it same search and select for inline adding for client_subuser need to overide it widget by on ready js